# Can't join two collections in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to join two collections through populate function. In particular, I need some properies from profile model in my user model. So I have done the following:

**User model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create schema
const userSchema = new Schema({
  profile: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'profiles'
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  score: {
    type: Number,
    default: 0
  },
  avatar: {
    type: String
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
```

**Profile model**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Create schema
const ProfileSchema = new Schema({
  user: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'users'
  },
  handle: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    max: 40
  },
  country: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  city: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  languages: {
    type: [String],
    required: true
  },
  bio: {
    type: String
  },
  gender: {
    type: String
  },
  education: {
    type: String
  },
  social: {
    vk: {
      type: String
    },
    instagram: {
      type: String
    },
    facebook: {
      type: String
    }
  }
});

module.exports = Profile = mongoose.model('profiles', ProfileSchema);
```

As you can see I have referenced one model in another. In the following code I populate a property when find users.

```
   // @route  GET api/words/leaders
    // @desc   Display leaders that contributed most to the project
    // @access Public
    router.get('/leaders', (req, res) => {
      User.find({})
        .populate('profile', ['handle'])
        .sort({ score: -1 })
        .then(users => res.json(users))
        .catch(err => res.status(404).json({ nonusersfound: 'No users found' }));


    });
```

Could you tell me what may cause a problem?

Comment: .populate({path: 'profile', select: 'handle'})
tryt this..!

Comment: @the_mahasagar, thanks for your answer, but it does not seem to work.

Comment: I have tried your code! and its working properly! can you share existing user/profile data in question? also current query output.!

Comment: @the_mahasagar, thanks for being interested in my problem, I have changed an approach and it works now.